# Excel Issue with using Concatenate & Increment while creating unique number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would greatly appreciate help on this issue I am having with excel

I have a table in excel and adding rows of data to it. For one column I am creating a unique number based on 4 cell values, and then have the last digit increment + 1. Right now I have a formula

```
=IF((OR($B5="BF",$B5="AD")),LEFT((TEXT([@(Current Date]],"MM"),2)&"-"&RIGHT(TEXT([@Current Date]],"YY"),2)&"-"&[BF/AD]&"-"&[CODE]&Rows()-4,"")
```

so the output looks like 07-21-BF-QA-1 and then the next row would be 07-21-BF-QA-2

so everything works BUT I can not use rows because I do not want the last number to change when a row is deleted. For auditing purposes, I need the number to not change. I have spent so much time trying to figure this out and no luck. I keep looking at alternate functions instead of rows but keep running into the same issue of the number automatically changing.

Please help!!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The only way to keep it the same if rows are deleted is to copy paste just the values back on top of itself.  Formula are live and no matter the method you use to create the end number, it will be effected if rows are deleted.  I would create a fifth column with the numbers static then concatenate that and then it will not change.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I would totally agree AS LONG as the `ROW()` statement is referencing the same tab, but what, if it references another one that can be **VeryHidden**?

Comment: @Qualia I stand corrected on the blanket statement.  But I still think it better to at some point make the numbers static by removing the formula part that creates it.  It just takes on user who thinks they know what they are doing to mess it all up.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with the following approach:

- Generate your **unique number** through a reference to a separate tab
- Hide that "tab" to avoid that someone removes a row in it.

Just replace your `ROWS()-4` command by `ROWS([Tabname]!A1)`.

The tab bar looks like this:
[image] or (if **Rows** is hidden) [image]

In my example, the formula is on **Output**, and `ROWS()` references cell `A1` on **Rows** tab.

**Output at the beginning**

[image]

**Output after removing row #6**

[image]

**Note**: Please note, that Excel has two to options for hiding tabs (xlSheetHidden and xlSheetVeryHidden). While the first one can be applied and undone via the Excel GUI, the second one can only be set and changed via VBA. Check **Worksheet**'s **Visible** property.
[image]